# stocks and flows in database design

Tags: database, database-design

I'm wondering what are best practices around recording stocks and flows. Do you store only flows, and calculate stocks? Or do you store both?

It seems like the important thing to persist are the flows. (For example, in a bank database, it would be debits and credits to an account), and the stocks (funds remaining) can be calculated from these. But if there are lots of bank accounts, and I want a table of multiple bank accounts with funds remaining, then I would have to recalculate this amount for each one. This seems quite slow.

On the other hand, I thought one of the main goals of databases is to not have duplicated data.

Is there a general practice around storing stocks? Should this be a calculated field, or rather inserted by program logic?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the problem you're running into?

Comment: The only "general practice" I'm aware of is "try it each way and see which one works best for your specific application, environment, and hardware, balancing speed against maintainability and insert, update, retrieval and delete speeds against each other."  I realize that that's pretty generic, but so was your question.

Answer (score 1):

In database design, we have **Derived Data**:

A table can have derived columns, which are columns for which values are **computed, based on the values of other table columns**. If all columns are derived, it is said to be a derived table.

For example:

- Student Age,
- Account Balance,
- Number of likes or up-votes and likes of posts and comments (like stackoverflow).

In this case we have 2 options with pros and cons:

1. **Delete** the derived data and calculate them

   - pros: we do not have any **Redundancy** in our database design.
   - cons: we should calculate the Aggregation data (Count, Sum, Avg,...) in most queries
2. **Use** derived data instead of calculate them

   - pros: we have all Aggregation data ready and do not need to calculate them
   - cons: we have a little **Redundancy**.
   - cons: we **should** update derived data when the original data changes.

**Therefor** we have a trade-off between choosing option 1 or 2. We should **calculate their costs** in our application and choose one of them.

**First**: Redundancy
I my idea the redundancy is not so important case in this trade-off. Because there is no so many duplicate data, we only use an extra field (like Integer of Big Integer)

**Second**: 
I think we **should calculate the costs** between these options:

1. in Deleting derived data

   - cost of **Performance** of retrieving Aggregation data
2. Using Aggregation columns

   - cost of **Updating** Aggregation columns

**So**, how can we calculate them in our application? There are some evaluation parameters that directly related to the cost:

1. the number of records in original table (and secondary table).
2. the number of inserts in original tables in a specified period of time.
3. the number of updates (update and delete)in original table in a specified period of time.
4. the number of selects from original data (or secondary table), containing Aggregation data, in a specified period of time
5. so many other parameters.

**Finally**: to get very formal approaches, I recommend to read [DAX Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/patterns/).